# Search inside a LIST only

Tags: search

lets suppose we have a list with 10 million rows.  I know that I can add webparts to the custom list default view page.

I wonder if there is any webpart that searches only inside that list, so I would put that webpart in that page and thats it.

Or do I have to make my own webpart for it?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, I think this link will lead you to the answer:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointsearch/thread/2529ba3e-9cd6-4f83-9258-435fedfc1e96

(The post by Gavin)

-V

Answer (score 0):

That's interesting.  In 2007 there were options to search "this list" and "this site."  It didn't occur to me before your question that "this site" is now the only option.

One thing you could do is drop an HTML Form Web Part in a web part zone on the page.  Then add a connection from your list for getting the filter value from the Form WP.  If you have multiple fields on which you want to filter, you would have to add all of the field to the Form WP.

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: Open the page in edit mode and choose add a web part in one of the zones.  Then select the HTML Form Web Part from the list.  It will give you a form with a single field (default name is T1) and a go button.  In your list view, click the down arrow on the right side of the web part title bar.  Choose connections --> Get Filter Values from.  Select your form, and then the field T1 and associate it with the list field that you want to filter.  You can edit the html in the form manually if you want to add more columns and labels to the form.

Answer (score 0):

So I think you might want to take a look at a nice solution that flexes the power of jquery

I have to say that I just dug this article up quickly and you might find other related articles that suit your fancy.  But yes this can be done with jquery and a content editor web part.

[link text](http://platinumdogs.wordpress.com/2009/08/21/sharepoint-contacts-list-search-with-auto-suggest-no-code-required/)